# Are there any resources or books available to understand the function load_elf_binary?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, elf

Please suggest some good resource to understand the function load_elf_binary...I have tried googlin on the topic but was unable to find anything helpful.

Comment: oh...vague????I have a problem in understanding a function load_elf_binary..I named  the exact function..is it stil vague and broad?

Answer (score 2):

["Linkers and Loaders"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960) by John Levine.